# Securing VPN access using the Always On Technology or 3rd party VPN clients?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, vpn-client, network-security

I'm using Hybrid Azure AD Join for all my Windows 10 & 11 Workstations, but not for the Windows Server OS.

So rather than manually deploying the 3rd Party VPN client to each workstation, can I use Always On VPN or Microsoft Entra VPN offerings?

Here is the list of 3rd Party VPNs list I am trialling:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-access/overview-always-on-vpn
https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/sase/globalprotect
https://docs.fortinet.com/sdwan

I am seeking guidance regarding the nuanced distinctions and similarities between the Always On VPN and the VPN solutions provided by Palo Alto and Fortinet as in the above list.

I'm keen to hear the pros and cons of each, as well as how they'd fit into our network architecture. It would also be useful to know how much maintenance would be required for each. I'm sure that would help us make an informed decision for our company.

I would appreciate any assistance you could provide in shedding light on this matter.

Thank you in advance.